# Permission Management in Asp.net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to asp.net identity framework. I do have experience in Session Management in asp.net webforms, php but identity framework is something new to me. I have the following questions.

Does Identity Framework allows for dynamic permissions assignment and management in asp.net mvc? Tagging controller methods with [Authorized] is not going to cut it, because it would mean recompiling the application each time permissions are changed. Additionally a more atomic level permission management is not easily achieved.

For example i have userrights in this xml file.

```
<modules>
<module>
    <id>FModule</id>
    <allowedusers>
        <user>
            <userid>1234</userid>
                <permissions>
                    <read>true</read>
                    <add>true</add>
                    <del>false</add>
                    <reporting>true</reporting>
                    <Districts>
                        <district>District 1</district>
                        <district>District 2</district>
                    </Districts>
                    <Projects>
                        <project>Project 1</project>
                        <project>Project 2</project>
                    </Projects>
        </user>
    </allowedusers>
</module>
```

As can be seen in the above file, the application is divided into Modules, and each user has rights assigned to that module. Generally my technique would be to

1) Authenticate the User
2) Check the Xml file for the logged in User permissions.
3) Store the user permissions in Session. 
4) Allow access to controller methods based upon the permissions.

Is there any better way to do it in Identity management? Is there any better technique to store user permissions (other than in an xml file).

Thanks in Advance.